# Why am I getting ,, Cannot read property 'load' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, cookies, session-cookies

I have defined cookie in my project like this. 
import cookie from 'react-cookie'. So that means I have defined cookie so I shouldn't be getting that error but sitll I am getting it.. I will share my code if anyone thinks it's needed.

*EDIT*
I om only adding here half of the code since I have to add some more details with the full code And I have no I idea what to add. The full code can be found here https://pastebin.com/APTdX879

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import Block from "./Block"
    import Add from './Add'
    import cookie from 'react-cookie'

    class App extends Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          logedin:  cookie.load("logedin")
        }
      }

      submit(){

        fetch("/newaccount")
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>{
          console.log(data)
          console.log(document.getElementById('username').value)
          let arr = data.filter(event=>{

            return (event.username==document.getElementById('username').value&&event.password==document.getElementById('password').value)
          })
          console.log(arr.length)
          console.log(arr)
          if(arr.length==1){
            this.setState({logedin:true})
          }
          else{
            alert("wrong useranme or password")
          }
        })
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        fetch("/api")
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=> this.setState({data: data}))
        .catch(error=>console.log(error+' 1'))
      }
      componentWillMount() {

    }

      render() {
        if(!this.state.logedin){
          return (
            <div>
            <input id="username"/>
            <input id='password' type="password"/>
            <button onClick={this.submit.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
            </div>
            )
        }

        if(!this.state.data){
        return <p>loading</p>
      }
        return (

          <div>
          <hr/>
          <Add/>
          {
            this.state.data.map((data,i)=>{
            return(
              <div key={i+"a"}>
              <Block name={data.username} img={data.img} date={data.date} text={data.text} likes={data.likes} comments={data.comments} key={i} id={data._id}></Block>
            <br key={i+"b"}/>
            </div>
            )
          })
        }
          </div>
```

*Second EDIT here is a screenshot of the error http://prntscr.com/gghb5p .

Comment: We can't help you from a description. Please provide the code and the exact error message. You could read https://stackoverflow.com/help-how-to-ask for information on how to get people to help you

Comment: What is the error, and which line of code does it  happen at

Comment: @Mikkel I just added a screenshot that contains information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the react-cookie documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie you should import it like this:

```
import { CookiesProvider, withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
```

And then getting a cookie in the constructor won't work, you will need to do it in the `componentWillMount()` method like this:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    const { cookies } = this.props;

    this.state = {
      name: cookies.get('name') || 'Ben'
    };
  }
```

Comment: why getting a cookie in the constructor won't work ?

Comment: It's to do with the timing. the constructor is where you will set default values, and methods like componentWillMount are done later (just before render), which is when you want to be loading data and state from the environment. There is an article about it here for you to read: http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Comment: When I attempted to add your code I got. Props is not defined.

Comment: I just cut and paste some of the code from the documentation - why don't you read that and see how it works

Answer (score 0):

try to inject it first:

```
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';

export default withCookies(App);
```

or

```
App = withCookies(App);
```

and then in your constructor:

```
    this.state = {
      logedin:  props.cookies.get("logedin")
    }
```

EDIT: in documentation of `react-cookie` there is no load method, I think you need

```
logedin:  props.cookies.get("logedin")
```

Comment: I got failed to compile.

Comment: @PetarPtolomejStojanov `export default withCookies(App);`, sorry

Comment: When I added default. I got the same error. Before making your changes.

Comment: did you change prop name from  `cookie` to `cookies` - `props.cookies.load` ? What if you do console.log(props); ?

Comment: use `get` instead `load` and change `cookie` to `cookies` . Do you get the same error?.

Comment: Have you set <CookiesProvider /> on top of your app like they say in docs?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie#cookiesprovider-

Comment: I tried got cookiesProvider is not defined. I have no idea where they defined cookiseProvider http://prntscr.com/gghn00. I am rage quting fro now. Is there a way I can close the thread or label it as solved.

Comment: @PetarPtolomejStojanov you need to import it before you use it `import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';`

Comment: @PetarPtolomejStojanov You can, however I use library `js-cookie` https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie. It doesn't require all the extra hussle, just to install it, import it like: `import Cookies from 'js-cookie';` and use it: `Cookies.get('name');`

Comment: thank you very much I downloaded that dependency it was so easy. Thanks thanks thanks.

Comment: @PetarPtolomejStojanov No problem. If I helped please upvote or accept the answer ;)